# User input in R

Tags: r, function, user-input, readline

I am trying to run an R script, using `Rscript` in Windows command prompt and ask for user's input.

So far, i have found answers on how to implement something similar in R's interactive shell. `readline()` or `scan()` doesn't seem to work for the command prompt.

Examples:

I have a polynomial `y=cX` where `X` can take more than one values `X1`,`X2`,`X3` and so on. `C` variable is know,  so what i need in order to calculate the value of `y` is to ask the user for the `Xi` values and store them somewhere inside my script.

The script bellow does nothing.

```
UIinput <- function(){

    #Ask for user input
    x <- readline(prompt = "Enter X1 value: ")

    #Return
    return(x)
}
```

The second example below just prompts the message and then ends.

```
FUN <- function(x) {

    if (missing(x)) {
        message("Uhh you forgot to eneter x...\nPlease enter it now.")
        x <- readLines(n = 1)
    }
    x
}
FUN()
```

Console output:

```
Uhh you forgot to eneter x...
Please enter it now.
character(0)
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cat("input x: ")
x <- readLines(con="stdin", 1)
cat(x, "\n")
```

Comment: give me some time please to implement your answer